# Where is SQL Server backup job running from?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

We run our daily/weekly backups from CA D-Series job scheduling tool. I perform daily differentials and weekly fulls on our SQL Server 2012 databases. I am finding every few days both the differential and full backup will run on our largest databases (the maintenance jobs are split into 4 streams going from smallest to largest databases). The full backup job does not look to be running from D-Series.

For instance, the last full ran on 7/29 and today 8/1 a differential ran at 1 am and a full executed at 3 am. I am trying to find where the job is running from. It filled up the disk. I looked at the application log / SQL Server log / Agent log and cannot find any location. It is driving me insane!

This is a production server so I cannot implement auditing due to the high activity. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maintenance plans create agent jobs for the sub-tasks. Have you checked the job history for those? They are usually named `MaintPlanName.SubTaskName`. I assume you are using these based on your mention of *the maintenance jobs*. If you don't see the backup in the sql log, then you probably have trace flag 3226 on. Consider researching this and turning it off so successful backups are logged.

Comment: No agent jobs are used.  We do not use maintenance plans.  All backups are scripted and executed from D-Series.  I saw the backups in the log, but cannot find where originating.

Comment: What’s the log entry look like? Third party backups usually stand out.

Comment: Message
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 516 pages in 0.870 seconds (4.633 MB/sec).

Message
Database backed up. Database: PROD, creation date(time): 2018/03/21(12:46:47), pages dumped: 522, first LSN: 168:1432:119, l
ast LSN: 168:1496:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'PRODBackup'}). This is an informational message 
only. No user action is required.

Comment: These are messages from today.   Do not understand the March date.

Comment: Was that database created or restored on this instance in March?

Comment: Yes.  Now I understand the date.  It is in regards to database creation, not backup.

Comment: I think you’ll need auditing here or restrict what users can backup the DB. This DB looks TINY though. It filled up the disk is odd to me

Comment: The database above is just an example.  The larger ones are 450 GB.  Auditing will impact db performance.

Comment: well, you could `DENY BACKUP DATABASE TO <....>` everyone except the login that's running it and prevent it :D

Comment: Are you on a version of SQL Server that supports extended events? If so, you *should* be able to set up a session to track restores.